# Variable Content Disappears

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a variable called dataShops created at the root of the function.

```
const fetchSales = () => {
    const dateInitial = moment(dayInitial, 'ddd, D MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    const dateFinal = moment(dayFinal, 'ddd, D MMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')

    let dataShops = []

    try {    
        setIsLoading(true)
        app.currentUser.customData.lojas.forEach(async (value, index) => {
            const mongo = app.currentUser.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas").db(value.base)
            const data = await mongo.collection("vendas").find({
                data: {
                    $gte: dateInitial,
                    $lte: dateFinal
                }
            }, { sort: { data: 1, hora: 1 } })
            dataShops = dataShops.concat(data)
            console.log(dataShops)//the data appears here
        })


        if (mounted) {
            console.log(dataShops) //at this point just an empty array
            setDataMain(dataShops)
        }
    } catch (e) {
        setError(e)
    } finally {
        setRefreshing(false)
        setIsLoading(false)
    }
}
```

I fill it inside a forEach and inside I can see its contents. But outside is just an empty array. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the callback function provided to `forEach` is an async function. That means the control flows to the following statement before the loop runs.

Once the `fetchSales` function finishes executing (which includes logging an empty array), the async functions in your for-each loop are fetched from the event queue and processed.

The easiest way to get around this is to use a regular `for` loop instead of for-each. This would however require you to declare the `fetchSales` method as  `async`.

Another option is to create an array of promises instead of using a `forEach` loop, and the waiting for all promises to resolve using `Promise.all` before accessing the values:

```js
let dataShops = []

try {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const promises = app.currentUser.customData.lojas.map((value) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const mongo = app.currentUser.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas").db(value.base);
      const data = await mongo.collection("vendas").find(
        {
          data: {
            $gte: dateInitial,
            $lte: dateFinal,
          },
        },
        { sort: { data: 1, hora: 1 } }
      );
      dataShops = dataShops.concat(data);
      resolve();
    });
  });

  Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
    if (mounted) {
      setDataMain(dataShops);
    }
    setRefreshing(false);
    setIsLoading(false);
  });
} catch (e) {
  setError(e);
}
```

Comment: Or replace `forEach` method with `map` and wait for it using `await Promise.all` if you don't want to use loops

Comment: @UğurEren Could you exemplify?

Comment: Thanks @UğurEren. I edited my answer and added your suggestion.

Comment: Missed put the async before the resolve... return new Promise(async(resolve) ...

Comment: Actually there is no need for returning a promise, async functions always [returns a promise.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value)